# Why am I obtaining this error message trying to connect and query a Firebase DB from an Angular 2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, javascript-framework

I am very new in Angular and Firebase and I am finding some difficulties trying to link a simple Angular application to a Firebase test DB (I am following a tutorial on Udemy and I can't understand why I am experimenting this issue).

I have this **AppComponent** main class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {database, initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor() {

    // Initialize Firebase:
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyAkgFXyAr8UeD9NPM2zU3J32CR_NvaBYHc",
      authDomain: "final-project-recording-bb15d.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://final-project-recording-bb15d.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "final-project-recording-bb15d",
      storageBucket: "final-project-recording-bb15d.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "295297957366"
    };


    initializeApp(config);


    var root = database().ref('testArray');

    root.on('value', function(snap) {
      console.log(snap.val());

    });


  }
}
```

As you can see I simple defined a constructor and into this constructor I declared the **var** object containing the information related to the connection info. Then I initialize my app passing these configuration info. Finnally I register the root node of my application on a specific **testArray** node defined into my Firebase DB and I set a listener to the change on this node.

The problem is that when I run the application with the **ng serve** statment I obtain no error into my IDE console but I obtain the following exception into my browser JavaScript console:

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:28)
    at createClass (core.js:12468)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12315)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13776)
    at createRootView (core.js:13665)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15090)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14373)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11260)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4031)
    at ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.js:5855)
View_AppComponent_Host_0 @ AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
proxyClass @ compiler.js:14647
DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:15030
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1488
(anonymous) @ core.js:5683
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4701
(anonymous) @ core.js:5683
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4753
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:870
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4744
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:594
Promise resolved (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:577
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:868
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:978
PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:5569
(anonymous) @ main.ts:12
../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:60
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
0 @ main.bundle.js:83
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_AppComponent_Host_0 @ AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
proxyClass @ compiler.js:14647
DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:15030
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1493
(anonymous) @ core.js:5683
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4701
(anonymous) @ core.js:5683
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4753
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:870
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4744
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:594
Promise resolved (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:577
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:868
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:978
PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:5569
(anonymous) @ main.ts:12
../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:60
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
0 @ main.bundle.js:83
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
zone.js:680 Unhandled Promise rejection: Object(...) is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:28)
    at createClass (core.js:12468)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12315)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13776)
    at createRootView (core.js:13665)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15090)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14373)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11260)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4031)
    at ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.js:5855) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at new AppComponent (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/app.component.ts:29:82)
    at createClass (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12664:20)
    at createDirectiveInstance (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12511:37)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13972:53)
    at createRootView (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13861:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15286:42)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14569:12)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11456:46)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4227:29)
    at ApplicationRef.bootstrap (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6051:57)
api.onUnhandledError @ zone.js:680
handleUnhandledRejection @ zone.js:707
_loop_1 @ zone.js:697
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:701
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:602
Promise resolved (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:577
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:868
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:978
PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:5569
(anonymous) @ main.ts:12
../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:60
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
0 @ main.bundle.js:83
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

Using the debugger the error seems happen when it try to execute this line:

```
var root = database().ref('testArray');
```

Why am I obtaining this error message? What am I missing? And what exactly means these error messages? How can I try to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: which version of firebase are you using

Answer (score 0):

```
import * from 'firebase/app';

firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

You need to select module initializeApp from firebase.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; import * from 'firebase/app';

@Component({   selector: 'app-root',   templateUrl: './app.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] }) export class AppComponent {   title = 'app works!';

  constructor() {

    // Initialize Firebase:
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyAkgFXyAr8UeD9NPM2zU3J32CR_NvaBYHc",
      authDomain: "final-project-recording-bb15d.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://final-project-recording-bb15d.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "final-project-recording-bb15d",
      storageBucket: "final-project-recording-bb15d.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "295297957366"
    };


    firebase.initializeApp(config);


    var root = database().ref('testArray');

    root.on('value', function(snap) {
      console.log(snap.val());

    });


  } }
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it seems can't work, please can you provide me the code of the entire class? (maybe I am missing something...)